# DXA 1.2 - Enabling object cache not working as expected

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, cache

DXA 1.2 ::  We have enabled EHCache in our application where we are caching only xml, JSON and txt files. Recently we also enabled Object Cache in cd_storage_conf.xml. Will there be any interference with the EHCache with this kind of setup? Our caching is not working as expected. The content, even binaries, is also not reflecting after publishing, which are not intended to cache.

Answer (score 2):

To directly answer your question ("Will there be any interference with EHCache with this kind of setup?"): Maybe, depending on how you set it up.

There could be issues on the EHCache setup (cache time too long), or issues on the Object Cache side (firewall blockage, incorrect configuration, jar file conflicts, and the list goes on).

First, you need to narrow down to where the problem lies. Does the problem go away when you disable Object Cache, but leave EHCache? Does the problem go away when you enable Object Cache, but disable EHCache?